# I installed SSL certificate in Apache, but weakness scan software show it has a wrong host vulnerabilities

Tags: laravel, apache, openssl, digicert

OS:Microsoft Server 2019

Web server:Apache

Frontend: Vue.js

Backend: Laravel

I'm setting port 443 to connect my vue.js project, and set port 9999 to connect laravel project.

When I going to "https://my_domain", it show SSL is valid in front of URL bar.

I use [Pentest-tools](https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/website-scanner) to scan "https://my_domain", the tools show the website is not have any vulnerability.

But when I using [Vooki](https://www.vegabird.com/vooki/) to scan my laravel API, it show I have a medium vulnerability which is "SSL-certificate wrong host".

where am I doing wrong? why when I go to vue.js using browser, it show I installed CA correct, but laravel API show "wrong host" in Vooki?

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\index"
    ServerName my_domain
    ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\vue_project_name"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\vue_project_name\css"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip my_ip
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\vue_project_name\js"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip my_ip
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2   
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Apache24\conf\ssl.key\my_domain.key"
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Apache24\conf\ssl.crt\my_domain.crt"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\Apache24\conf\DigiCertCA.crt"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9999>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\laravel_project_name\public"
    ServerName my_domain
    ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\laravel_project_name\public"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip my_ip
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2   
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Apache24\conf\ssl.key\my_domain.key"
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Apache24\conf\ssl.crt\my_domain.crt"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\Apache24\conf\DigiCertCA.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ServerName example.com

ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```

Comment: I put it in both of port 443 and port 9999, but it doesn't work, is still have "wrong host" vulnerability.

Comment: when you were setting up your SSL certificate did you specify both 'example.com' and 'www.example.com' to the authority issuing your SSL certificate ?

Comment: no, I just apply "example.com", no have "www.example.com", but it matter? Because I'm going to "example.com" to get my laravel API, not use "www.example.com".

Comment: yes it matters, you need to specify both when creating your ssl certificate

Comment: why it matters? Because laravel need a "www.*" domain name?

Comment: it has nothing to do with laravel or apache, who did you get the ssl cert from ?

Comment: on DigiCert website is asks you for 'Your main website URL' and also 'Additional standard or wildcard URLs', you enter example.com to the first and www.example.com to the second. You should use Lets Encrypt, they provide free SSL certs, don't know why anyone pays for SSL certs these days

Comment: It's my supervisor's decision. So how can I do any solution in this condition?

Comment: you are paying DigiCert for the SSL certificate so just contact them and tell them that you want to add 'Additional standard or wildcard URLs' to the certificate

Comment: OK, If I understand what are those relationship between"wrong host" and apply a "www.*" host.

Comment: But can you tell me why If I apply "www.example.com" in my SSL, I can resolve "wrong host" problem?